# How do I run Blender 2.79 on old GPU?

Tags: versions

I have a PC with an old intel GMA 945 that only supports openGL 2.0 and DirectX 9 and I want to install the latest version of blender. Everytime I try to run Blender 2.79 it gives me an openGL warning and crashes. I have updated my GPU driver to the absolute LATEST I can find,(Which is still about 5 years old). It is not my main PC but I want to use it alot more. Here are the specs:

4gb DDR2
Intel Core2 Duo 2.33ghz
120gb HDD
Intel GMA 945 128mb
Windows 7 Home